# Is my job classified as 'administration'?

Tags: salary

I have a question regarding what constitutes an administrative position.  I am currently on salary, and because of staff shortages it looks like I'm going to be hitting 100hrs this pay period.  I'm already looking into getting copies of my pay stubs to take to my state's labor department, but I'd like to have some idea of what constitutes an 'administrative' position for salary purposes.

I work for a solar panel installation company.  My work is a mixture of dispatching, data entry, report creation, and a dash of "graphic design".  I take calls from customers, work with our salespeople to make sure appointments are attended, enter the data from the initial consultation, and then draft up paperwork for the second consultation appointment.  I work in Sketchup to do layouts of our clients' homes, then take that and put it in a Word doc, and then use a program to create a report based upon the client's energy usage and possible costs of paying an electrical company vs getting solar panels installed.

There are aspects of this job that certainly seem administrative, and others that do not.  I do not have any managerial authority, I am not in charge of anyone, and though I work with our salespeople to assign appointments, I'm not in charge of scheduling or payrole or anything like that.

My question is - would all that be considered administrative for the purpose of me being paid a salary and being exempt from OT pay?

Thank you!

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking. It seems you are care mostly about getting over time pay, i.e exempt vs non-exempt status. This (at least in the US) is not related to whether you do administrative work or not. Since this is partially a legal question please add location to the question.

Comment: Most college graduates in the US are exempt employees, people who are paid a salary rather than an hourly wage. The employer does not have to pay overtime for exempt employees in the US. The rules differ markedly elsewhere. As is, there is no answer to this question because you did not say where you live.

Comment: How long is a pay period? If it is a month then 100 hours doesn't seem that high if one presumes 20 working days to a month.

Comment: My assumption was that a pay period must be weekly based on that comment - hitting 100 hours in a week should be by exception only in most places.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your duties are definitely administrative, but that's normal for most jobs. My take on this is you should get OT. Best practice in my experience is to assume you will get OT and ask politely for clarification if you don't. If you just let it slide, 100 hours might easily become what is normally expected of you..... hope that helps